# Is it possible to have separate docks for each monitor in a multy monitor setup?

Tags: plank

While I'm using a multiple monitor setup, I tend to check the bottom of the screen I'm looking at for the dock. Is it possible to get the dock on all the screens I have?

If it's a mini-dock - which keeps icons only for the windows that are available on the screen in question - would be better than the full dock.

If it's not possible, is there a way to suggest this as a feature to Elementary Team?

I feel most of the people with multiple monitor setup, face this annoyance.